# EF5 ASP.NET MVC 4 Linq query not returning anything & model property null -> Code First

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, code-first, datamapper

Im having trouble linking my loaned items to my Library for each customer. It does it fine when it goes through the "AddToLibrary" method but when it comes to retreiving it, the medialibrary is empty and the query in the `IEnumerable<Item> ItemsOnLoan method` is returning null. This is a very basic ASP.NET MVC 4 application and im very new to this so its probably something silly ive missed out.

I just want to be able to add an item to the loaned items table, have the list of loaned items for each customer appear in their personal Library (defined in model) and then retreive the list of their items. Below is all the code and I am using a code first approach. Thank you :)

Model

```
public class Customer
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string ForeName { get; set; }
        public string SurName { get; set; }
        public Address address { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Telephone { get; set; }
        public string Mobile { get; set; }
        public List<LoanedItem> Library { get; set; }

        public Customer()
        {

            if (Library == null || Library.Count == 0)
            {
                Library = new List<LoanedItem>();
            }
        }

        public IEnumerable<Item> ItemsOnLoan
        {
            get
            {
                var items = (from i in Library
                             where i.Customer.Id == this.Id
                             select i).OfType<item>();
                return items;
            }
        }
}
```

Loaned Item model

```
public class LoanedItem
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public MediaItem Item { get; set; }
}
```

ItemController  --> adding to library method

```
public ActionResult AddToLibrary(int id)
{

    Item libraryItem = db.Items.Find(id);
    Customer c = db.Customers.Find(1);
    LoanedItem newLoanGame = new LoanedItem()
    {
        Customer = c,
        Item = libraryItem
    };
    db.LoanedItems.Add(newLoanGame);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Customer Controller

```
public ActionResult ViewProfile(int id = 1)
{
    Customer c = db.Customers.Find(id);
    if (c == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(c);
}
public ActionResult GetLibraryItems(int id = 1)
{
    var items = db.Customers.Find(id).ItemsOnLoan;
    return View(items);
}
```

Context

```
public class LibraryContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<LoanedItem> LoanedItems { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Item> Items { get; set; }

    public LibraryContext()
        : base("LbContext")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new CustomerConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new LoanedItemConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.Entity<Item>();
        modelBuilder.Entity<Address>();

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that Proxy generation is enabled try this:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ForeName { get; set; }
    public string SurName { get; set; }
    public Address address { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Telephone { get; set; }
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<LoanedItem> ItemsOnLoan { get; set; }

    public Customer()
    {
    }
}
```

using this to acccess:

```
public ActionResult GetLibraryItems(int id = 1)
{
    var customer = db.Customers.Find(id);
    if (customer != null)
    {
        var items = customer.ItemsOnLoan;
        return View(items);
    }
    //handle not found or throw an exception
    throw new Exception();
}
```

follow [this link](http://buildstarted.com/2010/08/11/entity-framework-and-lazy-loading/) for more information on Proxies and Lazy Loading.

Comment: exception is: 
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: source

on the query
                var items = (from i in Library
                             where i.Customer.Id == this.Id
                             select i).OfType<Item>();

Comment: @user1290653 there is no `Game` class defined in the code above?

Comment: apologies, that was something else, ive change the comment

Comment: Get rid of the method as I have done above. Change `ItemsOnLoan` to be a `virtual ICollection<LoanedItem>`

Comment: how do I use that? sorry not good at using virtual, what will that do?

Comment: RIGHT it seems to be working, the Library is basically saving, brilliant, thank you very much. I knew it would be something small!